# Vue.js - Why can't I delete all items from an array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I got a parent component (a form) broken down into child components to handle different types of input data. The data is pre-populated from an API. If a user makes a new selection or changes some data in the child components, I want to emit it up to the parent component so I can use it in a form submit event and pass this new data to the database/API.

The above logic works on updates, **however, if the user wants to delete an item (by selecting the "X" button in the screenshot shown below), I need to also update the form result's array and not include the "deleted" item.** The form Results array kind of works, but for some reason I can't delete remove the cards from the UI:

[image: screenshot]

The parent component is passing down the form value props to the child and child is emitting the updates back up to parent:

```
<ISOAdminDivForm />
    <ISOAdminDivFormName />
        <ISOAdminDivFormNameItem />
```

Can someone check out my codesandbox demo and help me figure out why I can't dynamically delete the "cards" from the UI?

https://codesandbox.io/s/foundation-form-names-forked-tvwpu?file=/src/components/ISOAdminDivFormName.vue

Comment: You are doing this the wrong way. Your array in reactive, so you need to use [`Vue.delete`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete) in the parent's `language` method 'or create another event handler for deletion) to remove an element from a list and keep it reactive. What you are doing right now is setting a new array in `this.formValues`, but the original array used in the child's template does not change.

Comment: Any chance you can set up a codesandbox? I can't get this to work.

Comment: My bad, for arrays, the method to use is [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). I'll try to update your sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to have something working. It was actually simpler than I thought originally since you included many files (more than needed for a minimal, reproducible example).

Basically, it boils down to properly updating the `divisionLanguages` data property.

To make it simpler, I removed the `formValues` data since I think is just confusing and redundant with `divisionLanguages.data`.

As I said in my comments, to update a reactive list in Vue, you need to use [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

So your `deleteItem` method will need to find the index of the item to remove then splice the array with said index:

```
deleteItem(id) {
  const elementIndex = this.divisionLanguages.data.findIndex(
    (x) => x.P_uniqueID === id
  );
  this.divisionLanguages.data.splice(elementIndex, 1);
  this.$emit("languages", this.divisionLanguages.data);
}
```

Here is the forked sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/foundation-form-names-forked-b7sy2?file=/src/components/ISOAdminDivFormName.vue

Comment: Awesome! Let me give this a try and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that if you click the X button, the OTHER item is deleted, NOT the one that you thought you were deleting...can you confirm?

Comment: I had to modify `(x) => x.P_uniqueID !== id` to `(x) => x.P_uniqueID === id` on the `deleteItem()` method.

Comment: @redshift Ah indeed, that's an oversight on my part, thanks for spotting it.